# Javascript - How to change color of parts of an image

Tags: javascript, image

I have an image that is plain white. I'm using the `<map>` and `<area>` tags to make little sections that call a function, but I also want to change the color of each section. How can I do this?

**EDIT:** I also want to make it so that I can change the color later, and I want to use Javascript because the color depends on what a certain variable is.

**EDIT 2:** The color change can't just be on mouse over.

Comment: are you using a click or change jQuery function on the <map> or <area>?? ........ as in are you wanting to change the color of that section when some other interaction happens? or just change the color of it permanently?

Comment: just change it permanently... well, actually, I will want to change it to another color later, but it should start out being a certain color as soon as the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will initially set a color to it in css.

set an id to each of those tags

```
<map id="my_fake_id">
```

in CSS

```
#my_fake_id {
    color:#color_number;
}
```

to change it later all you have to do is call a function, check that the value is equal to what you want it to be equal to, then set the css color to what you want.

```
var change_color = function(param){
    var exampleValue = whatever-the-value-is;
    if(param == exampleValue){
       $("#my_fake_id").css('color','red');

    }
}
```

---

EDIT:
see this fiddle for the correct idea and starting point
http://jsfiddle.net/mrQJu/2/

Comment: I'm not a fan of inline styling but technically you could also do <map style="color:blue;">

Comment: in-line styling overrides other styles

Comment: honestly the best thing to do if your css style isn't working is to open the console, inspect the element that you are wanting to change, and then see what additional styles (on the right hand column) are preventing that color from getting on there.

Comment: I don't get what you mean.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49580/discussion-between-cpc-and-john-ruddell)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Per your comment on the original question, this will not change the color permanently, only temporarily on mouse over.

There's a couple of ways that you could do it. First would be to overlay some divs for each area of the `map` and color the divs. You can also do this by overlaying images and having an image appear over the section of the `map` that you hover the mouse over.
So for example, if you have a map of the world and you want to highlight North America on mouse over, make an image of the North America section of the map and overlay the div on the existing image so that it appears on mouse over.

A better (and easier way) to do this is to create one image that is the width of the original image times the number of `<area>`s plus 1. The left most area of this long image will have your original image, with copies of your original image stacked next to each other to the right, each copy with the desired area highlighted.

```
-------------------
|orig.|  1  |  2  |
|     |     |     |
-------------------
```

Then use CSS to shift the image to the left so that the highlighted area shows on mouse over. This has the added advantages of only needing to load one image in the browser, and it also reduces flicker.

Hope this makes sense; if you need further clarification leave a comment.

Comment: how would I make it change permanently? or at least until I change it later.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work

```
<area shape="rect" COORDS="0,0,800,600" href="#" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#00FF00';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='transparent';"/>
```

Or if you want to change the color if the user selects it

```
<area shape="rect" COORDS="0,0,800,600" href="#" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor='#00FF00';"/>
```

If the color is based on a variable... 
use `onclick = changeMyColor()`

```
function changeMyColor(){
  var changeThisColor = document.getElementById('yourElement');
  changeThisColor.innerHTML += '<area style="background-color:'+ yourColorVariable +';"  
}
```

Comment: I just want it to be that color no matter where the mouse is.

Comment: did you try it inline? <area style="color:blue;"> ? its not a great coding habit but that would change the color

Comment: I replied to that on your answer.